# A question related to fiber bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Let $f:\mathbb{C}^3 \to \mathbb{C}$ be a morphism of varieties such that it is a smooth fiber bundle. Can I say that the fiber is $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Comment: A smooth morphism in the sense of algebraic geometry, or just a $C^{\infty}$ fiber bundle which happens to be a morphism of varieties?

Comment: @BenMcKay Aren't these equivalent if the source and the target are smooth as varieties?

Comment: @Oniqa I can see three different settings for this problem. Firstly, the context of complex algebraic geometry . Then $f$ must be a complex polynomial on $z_1$, $z_2$, $z_3$. Secondly, the complex analytic situation. Thirdly, in the category of smooth manifolds. In the latter category the answer is no.  If one considers an exotic $M=\mathbb{R}^4$ then $M\times \mathbb{C}$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^3=\mathbb{R}^6$, because $\mathbb{R}^6$ unlike $\mathbb{R}^4$ has a unique smooth structure. The projection $p_2\colon M\times \mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is then taken for $f$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $f$ is smooth as a map of varieties. If $f$ comes from a direct product $\mathbb{C}^3\approx S\times \mathbb{C}$ then $S\approx \mathbb{C}^2$. See Section 5.1 of [$\mathbb{A}^1$-homotopy theory and contractible varieties: a survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.07851)

I do not see why $f$ must come from a direct product so this is not a complete answer.